# getExportedKeys() in JDBC returns empty set in mysql

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am using `getExportedKeys` JDBC method. It is working fine in Oracle but in MySQL it is returning empty set. I tried using `useInformationSchema=true`, still it returns empty set.
Let me know whether `getTables,getExportedKeys,getImportedKeys` works for MySQL, sql , DB2 , Postgres database.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the driver and DataSource that you use.
Some DataSorce implementation provide option to enable disable DatabaseMetadata for better performance.

For example: Refer to the below information from link 
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E21764_01/web.1111/e13753/db2.htm#JDBCD153

--->>CatalogOptions

Determines which type of metadata information is included in result sets when an application calls DatabaseMetaData methods.

Valid Values: 0 | 2 | 6 and the default value is 2.

If 0, result sets do not contain synonyms.

If 2, result sets contain synonyms that are returned from the following DatabaseMetaData methods: getColumns(), getExportedKeys(), getFunctionColumns(), getFunctions(), getImportedKeys(), getIndexInfo(), getPrimaryKeys(), getProcedureColumns(), and getProcedures().

If 6, a hint is provided to the driver to emulate getColumns() calls using the ResultSetMetaData object instead of querying database catalogs for column information. Result sets contain synonyms. Using emulation can improve performance because the SQL statement that is formulated by the emulation is less complex than the SQL statement that is formulated using getColumns(). The argument to getColumns() must evaluate to a single table. If it does not, because of a wildcard or null value, for example, the driver reverts to the default behavior for getColumns() calls. <<<------